# keyboard shortcut to send a file as mail attachment

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, attachments

Is there any shortcut or way to create a shortcut to attach selected file as mail attachment in Outlook. Now, I've to right click the selected file and use "Send To-->Mail Recipient" option. A shortcut will help a lot.

Comment: Currently selected in what? Outlook? Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> in outlook will open new email. You can copy past the attachment to the new email.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There is no default Windows shortcut, however you would be able to create your own using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)

Comment: I seriously should start using it, if you see how many things there are you would want to HotKey

Answer (score 1):

For those who like to work at the command line, check out [blat](http://www.blat.net/). Once configured, it can be used to form *and send* a complete email from a single command. Note that blat is a complete mail user agent itself: it does not use Outlook or any other mailer on the PC.

For example, the following command:

```
C:\...>blat -to someone@example.com -subject "Totality" -attach total.jpg -body "Here's that shot of the total eclipse"
Blat v2.6.2 w/GSS encryption (build : Feb 25 2007 12:06:19)

Sending stdin.txt to someone@example.com
Subject: Totality
Login name is me@example.com
Attached binary file: total.jpg

C:\...>
```

Sends a photo along with a short text caption to a single recipient, printing some reassuring progress notes along the way.

It is actually quite the powerful tool, and can be handy if you need to have a long-running (or scheduled at odd times) batch job that you'd like to report results from.

Answer (score 1):

I have Outlook 2010.  The answer here is simply: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, then AF.  This will bring up your word files for attachment.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the default ALT (underlined) shorcuts, so for Sent to Mail Recipient:

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try the following sequence: <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Just remember, ALT F.H.E.A! That's ALT+ F,H,E,A

I know it's long but it actually works!

Your welcome

Comment: Can you explain specifically what this does?

Comment: Pressing and releasing ALT in Office programs activates a legacy menu emulation mode that uses single letters for selecting Ribbon Tabs and commands. Originally it was added for those used to the pre-ribbon menu shorts where you could use ALT+Menu Letters. Holding ALT down while hitting the keys executes the final command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the word document, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd> goes through the menu items `File > Share > Email > Attachment`.

*Edit: You can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>*

A blank e-mail is created with the document attached.

If you are in Windows Explorer, and have the file selected, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> works. However, I am using Windows 8, so this could be unique to that OS, not 100% sure though.

Comment: ALT+# executes a Quick Access Toolbar shortcut, so you must have the email as attachment on your QAT.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Quick Access Toolbar at the top left of the program. Click on the More button to add an icon, such as 'Email'

This takes seconds to set up and is then on your Quick Access Toolbar to click when you want from Word, or Excel or another Office program. You'll need to add the button to the program you want to send the file from.

If you want a more complex icon such as to Email a PDF of your document, choose More Commands, then from Choose Commands from, change 'Popular Commands' to 'All Commands' and you'll find many useful icons including 'Email as PDF Attachment'.

If you want a quick video tutorial I think I did one on my blog some time ago if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Alt + S + E (window 10 maybe others too)

Answer (score 0):

Alt F H E A use to be my shortcut. In the latest version of Excel that put me in the search box for my files.

New version of Excel (MS Excel for MS365 MSO)

Alt F Z Tab Enter

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> attaches the current powerpoint to Outlook.

Answer (score -1):

ctrl+Alt+F

This will pull the email selected and add it as an attachment in a new email.